# Who are the youngest ever bowlers to 50, 100 and 150 test wicket?

Tags: cricket, trivia

How does Kagiso Rabada figure into the youngest players to 50, 100 and 150 test wickets, does he make the top 5 in all three cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rabada was the 15th youngest bowler to 50 Test wickets (top 5: Mohammad Aamer, Waqar Younis, DL Vettori, I Sharma, Mehedi Hasan).

He was the 5th youngest to 100 wickets (top 5: Kapil Dev, DL Vettori, Waqar Younis, Harbhajan Singh, K Rabada).

He was the 2nd youngest to 150 wickets (top 5: Waqar Younis, K Rabada, Harbhajan Singh, Kapil Dev, Saqlain Mushtaq).